# proguard rule not working for some Java files

Tags: java, android, kotlin, proguard, android-room

I am using room database library and interface has method

```
@Query(Select * from employee where deptName = :DeptName)
List<Employee> getAllEmployeeFrom(deptName: String);
```

I have applied proguard rule:

```
-keep interface androidx.* { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembernames public interface packagename.dao.*{*;}
-keepclasseswithmembernames public class packagename.dao.*$DefaultImpls{*;}
```

But final class generated after proguard obfuscation is

```
@Query(Select * from employee where deptName = :DeptName)
List getAllEmployeeFrom(deptName: String);
```

Here the List is missing. Please help me to understand why List type is changed. Also the same code written in Kotlin works fine. I cannot migrate Java file to Kotlin. The proguard rule has to be written for java files.

Answer (score 0):

> The -keep option specifies the entry point of the application that has
>   to be preserved.

```
-keep class packageName.Employee ** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class packageName.Employee ** { *; }
```

Comment: "Employee is an entity. If I have n no.of entities in a pkg, Do I need to write n no.of -keep stmts for each entity?"

Comment: @Barungupta `Do I need to write n no.of -keep stmts for each entity?` you can

Answer (score 0):

You must use *-keepattributes Signature* in order to keep the generic in the list.

According to Proguard documentation (https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/configuration/examples#library)

> The "Signature" attribute is required to be able to access generic types.